# nodejs async error typeof arr.length === "number"

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to use async.series to get three functions to run synchronously.

the condensed code what i am using is as below:

```
var async = require('async');


function round(rnum, rlength) {
    return newnumber = Math.round(rnum * Math.pow(10, rlength)) / Math.pow(10, rlength);
}

function roundup(rnum, rlength) {
    return newnumber = Math.ceil(rnum * Math.pow(10, rlength)) / Math.pow(10, rlength);
}

function rounddown(rnum, rlength) {
    return newnumber = Math.floor(rnum * Math.pow(10, rlength)) / Math.pow(10, rlength);
}

function fun_auth_pwdLogin(_html) {
    //do something
}

var login = function () {
    //do something        
}
exports.login = login;



function RunScrapingPositions(callbackDone) {
    status = false;
    myhttp.get('https://example.com/PB.jsp',
            function (_html) {
            if (_html && _html.length > 10) {
            //do something                   
            } else {
                callbackDone();
                }
    })  
}



function RunScrapingOrderBook(callbackDone) {
    status = false;
    myhttp.get('https://example.com/OB.jsp',
            function (_html) {
            if (_html && _html.length > 10) {
            //do something
            } else {
                callbackDone();
                }   
    }); 
}



function RunScrapingMarketWatch(callbackDone) {
    myhttp.get('https://example.com/MW.jsp',
            function (_html) {
            if (_html && _html.length > 10) {
            //do something
            } else {
                callbackDone();
                }
    }); 
}



async.series([
    RunScrapingPositions,
    RunScrapingOrderBook,
    RunScrapingMarketWatch
    ],function () {
        console.log('Executed scraping in series');
        }
);
```

When I run this code, am getting the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:74
            typeof arr.length === "number" &&
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at _isArrayLike (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:74:23)
    at _parallel (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:710:23)
    at async.series [as _onTimeout] (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:734:9)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

What am I doing wrong?  If this error is related to the callback contents, please let me know so i can add the contents of these functions in the code also.

I also observe that before the error comes, the first and third function is called, but somehow the second function RunScrapingOrderBook is not being run - not sure if this will get resolved if the above error is resolved.

Clueless for now :-)

Comment: Can you reduce the example to an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will execute and still reproduce the error? Be sure to include any `require` statements that are needed.

Comment: Hi, the issue seems to have been a wrongly defined callback in one of the functions - - it is working fine now -- Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at async source, but I would default to passing the values that the async documentation suggests, https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback

If i'm reading it correctly, your task callbacks require an error as the first param, (I think to short circuit execution, if one of the tasks return an error):

```
function RunScrapingMarketWatch(callbackDone) {
    myhttp.get('https://example.com/MW.jsp',
            function (_html) {
            if (_html && _html.length > 10) {
            //do something
            } else {
                var err = null;
                callbackDone(err);
                }
    }); 
}
```

---

I don't think it causes the error that you're seeing, but the series complete callback accepts, an error, and an array of results:

```
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```